# Merging multiple dataframes and summing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple dataframes, all having the same shape but with different values. I need to merge the dataframes into one and add the values in the A, B, and C columns. Below is an example:

df1:

```
**Name,A,B,C**  
Fred, 3, 4, 5  
Tim, 1, 3, 0  
Jake,4,2,10
```

df2:

```
**Name,A,B,C**  
Fred, 1,0,4  
Tim, 7,1,2  
Jake,3,3,1
```

What I'm looking for is such:

df_merged:

```
**Name,A,B,C**  
Fred,4,4,9  
Tim,8,4,2  
Jake,7,5,11
```

Keep in mind that I have multiple dataframes that need merged into 1 (6+).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `sum` by [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, ...]
df = pd.concat(dfs).groupby('Name', as_index=False).sum()
```

---

```
dfs = [df1, df2]
df = pd.concat(dfs).groupby('Name', as_index=False).sum()
print (df)
   Name  A  B   C
0  Fred  4  4   9
1  Jake  7  5  11
2   Tim  8  4   2
```